# How to use PM2 auto build after changed code

Tags: reactjs, pm2

I create server `reactjs` with `nginx`, and i need auto build system when code changed after run `git pull` like `nodemon` using PM2 but running script `npm run build && cp ./build/* /usr/share/nginx/html`

Answer (score 0):

You can try with express to render build file.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.static('/usr/share/nginx/html'));
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile('/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html');
});
app.listen(3000);
```

And save this code snippet as server.js for example, and run this command

```
pm2 start server.js
```

And when you run git pull and build commands, it will render updated changes automatically.

Hope this helps you to understand. (don't forget to install express)

Comment: where locate server.js..? inside react js app?

Comment: put that file in private folder that you think safe. In my case, I put that file in home directory. And this pm2 process will trigger build file changes automatically even it's located anywhere.